# Red5: is it alright to store IConnection instances in a HashMap to retrieve later

Tags: red5

I have a `HashMap` defined like this

```
HashMap<String, IConnection> connections = new HashMap<String, IConnection>();
```

inside application `connect`, I add values into it like this:

```
conn.setAttribute(“username”, username);
connections.put(username, conn); // username and conn are parameters passed to 
                                 // connect method
```

inside application `disconnect` method, I remove values from it like this

```
connections.remove((String)conn.getAttribute(“username”));
```

This seems to work, however is it correct/safe? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Seems fine by me. But, why are you doing this?

Comment: my app is designed in a way that I sometimes need to get connection associated with a particular username, so I do a `connections.get(“buzzLightYear”)` and it returns me the connection associated with buzzLightYear, then I can call client methods on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is alright but I suggest that you make sure the connection is still connected before you try to access or write to it.